# Nativescript Run (iOS) Almost Never Works Anymore

Tags: angular, xcode, macos, nativescript

I am trying to run my Nativescript program on my iOS device. Running tns run ios results in all normal build logs until it reaches "Xcode Build...", where it will stay forever 95% of the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. And I have no clue why.

I've tried everything and I can't figure out why it works sometimes and doesn't work other times. Restarting my computer doesn't help. Everything is up to date. I also disabled Wifi sync in iTunes (saw in another post). Deleting platforms and node_modules doesn't help either. Even running on the Emulator does not work.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus": "^2.2.0",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "^8.0.1",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.2.1",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-facebook-account-kit": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-http-formdata": "^1.7.0",
    "nativescript-imagecropper": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-stripe": "^5.4.3",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^6.0.0",
    "parse-usdl": "git+https://github.com/kdagnan/parse-usdl.git",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.4.3",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^0.6.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.0.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.10.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.4.2"
  },
```

```
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.NyteProto",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.4.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.4.2"
    }
  },
```

I really am at a loss here. I really like Nativescript but this is bugging me to no end. I spend hours every day just fidgeting with the Run command to actually see my changes work. Once it installs one time, updates via HMR work most of the time as well.

EDIT: Same issue with tns build ios. I think it's an XCode issue possibly?

Comment: Are you using cloud builds?

Comment: I was using local builds but just confirmed that it works fine on a cloud build. I already tried a clean install of Xcode, as I figured that might be the issue. Is there any way to view the log files that Xcode generates when tns run is happening? Because all I see is "Xcode build..." then "Installing" but nothing in between that.

Comment: May be your memory? Which mac you are using?

Comment: 2016 15" MBP. 16GB RAM, 2.9Ghz i7, Radeon RX 580. Looking at ActivityMonitor, I seem to have a lot (10+) of "node" processes running, which seem to be coming from my project. Is this a leak or am I doing something wrong?